# Banner Images Not Rotating After Setting Up JQuery Rotate

Tags: jquery

I have several jpgs that need to rotate through a div.  I donwloaded jquery-rotate and setup what I thought to be the correct layout.  However, only the first image displays, and not the 2 through 4 images.  Am I using the improper plugin to shuffle through these 4 images?  Here's my code:

```
<div id="bannercontainer">                      
    <div id="banner"><img src="css/images/banner1.jpg" alt=""></img></div>
    <div id="banner"><img src="css/images/banner2.jpg" alt=""></img></div>
    <div id="banner"><img src="css/images/banner3.jpg" alt=""></img></div>
    <div id="banner"><img src="css/images/banner4.jpg" alt=""></img></div>
</div>
```

Here's the script and CSS snippets:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.rotate/jquery-1.5.min.js"/>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.rotate/jquery.rotate.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#bannercontainer").rotate();
    });
</script>

#bannercontainer{
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width: 775px;
    height:148px;
}
#banner div{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Thanks much for your advice and guidance!

UPDATE:  After implementing JQuery Cycle, my code is as follows:

```
<div id="bannercontainer">
    <img src="css/images/banner1.jpg" alt=""></img>
    <img src="css/images/banner2.jpg" alt=""></img>
    <img src="css/images/banner3.jpg" alt=""></img>
    <img src="css/images/banner4.jpg" alt=""></img>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bannercontainer{
    position:relative;
    width: 775px;
    height:148px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#bannercontainer img{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"/>   
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.bannercontainer').cycle({
            fx: 'fade'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately, my images still don't fade as intended.

Comment: What plugin are you using? A link to one would help as the jquery.rotate.js found here (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/) is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element has id bannercontainer but you are using a class selector.

```
$('.bannercontainer').cycle({
```

should be

```
$('#bannercontainer').cycle({
```

Comment: Doh!! :)  Thanks!!  Fixed that.  Also added speed: 300  and timeout: 2000 but images just load quickly at first load then no fade effect.

Comment: JSfiddle flags the separate closing tag as an error `<img src="css/images/banner4.jpg" alt=""></img>`.  Did you try self-closing tags? `<img src="css/images/banner4.jpg" alt="" />`

Comment: Hi Dennis,  Great suggestion on JSFiddle, I hadn't used it before.  I changed to self-closing tags, but the page is still not rendering a rotating image.

Comment: I also found that my script tags could not be self-closing.  That was causing the plugin to not function.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a slideshow which is different from rotating an image on its own 
axis, which jquery.rotate.js does.
Perhaps this will help
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/